# Function to iterate through a list and sum columns based on conditional statement

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes that look like (sample dput attached below):

```
[[1]]
                 SPY.HIGH   SPY.ADX  SPY.MA  SPY.CLOSE
2014-08-11        -1          1       1      5
2014-08-12        -1          1       1     10

[[2]]]
                  MSCI.HIGH MSCI.ADX MSCI.MA  MSCI.CLOSE 
2014-08-29        -1          -1       1      3
2014-09-01        -1           1       1      1
2014-09-02         0          -1       0      2
```

I'm trying to create a function that would only sum up the last columns of the above data sample based on the conditions that the first column is nonzero, second column is positive and third column is nonnegative. I made the following attempt:

```
marketsum <- function(x) {
  #Conditional columns
  validrows <- FlaggingTrend[[x]][,1] != 0 | FlaggingTrend[[x]][,2] > 0 | FlaggingTrend[[x]][,3] != 0

  # Only calculates the sum of fourth column for the rows if above conditions are met
  sum(FlaggingTrend[[x]][validrows,4])
}

returnsum <- list()

# Use sapply to run function to work out sums 
returnsum <- sapply(1:length(FlaggingTrend), function(x) marketsum(x))
```

However, I'm getting `NA` instead of summed values?

```
names close
1    EUR    NA
2    JPY    NA
3    GBP    NA
4    CHF    NA
5    AUD    NA
6    CAD    NA
7    NZD    NA
```

I would appreciate help or guidance as to where I'm going wrong. Sample dput is attached below:

```
list(structure(list(EUR.CLOSE = c(-1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 
0, 1), EUR.CLOSE.1 = c(1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1), EUR.50D = c(-1, 
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), EUR.CLOSE.2 = c(-0.0011268664916733, 
-0.00423709498833686, -0.00188893142678216, 0.00217196364717242, 
0.00686254162079234, -0.00544858088184653, -0.000188412624203348, 
-0.00737591996472312, 0.00208590196044455, 0.00227057808051545
)), .Names = c("EUR.CLOSE", "EUR.CLOSE.1", "EUR.50D", "EUR.CLOSE.2"
), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", "2017-02-15", 
"2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", "2017-02-21", "2017-02-22", 
"2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(JPY.CLOSE = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1), JPY.CLOSE.1 = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, 
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), JPY.50D = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1), JPY.CLOSE.2 = c(-0.000264935754629825, 0.00458231327013969, 
0.00456141141766331, -0.000875580127735809, -0.00809151292488242, 
-0.00353857410990255, 0.00230149698827908, 0.00511510066677001, 
-0.00326005839636956, -0.00619690368354142)), .Names = c("JPY.CLOSE", 
"JPY.CLOSE.1", "JPY.50D", "JPY.CLOSE.2"), row.names = c("2017-02-10", 
"2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", 
"2017-02-20", "2017-02-21", "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(GBP.CLOSE = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 
    1), GBP.CLOSE.1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), GBP.50D = c(-1, 
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), GBP.CLOSE.2 = c(-0.00048023051987453, 
    0.00279809911944895, -0.00464112219813048, -0.000561594944360089, 
    0.0022444899202175, -0.00618451029481418, 0.00410050825810596, 
    0.000802053299332334, -0.00184568523285542, 0.00847801606899046
    )), .Names = c("GBP.CLOSE", "GBP.CLOSE.1", "GBP.50D", "GBP.CLOSE.2"
    ), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", 
    "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", "2017-02-21", 
    "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
        CHF.OPEN = c(1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1), CHF.OPEN.1 = c(-1, 
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1), CHF50D = c(1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), CHF.OPEN.2 = c(0.000698567964139939, 
        0.00328669186857626, 0.00049704260678339, -0.000695928844511353, 
        -0.00838914337795957, 0.00550083899465574, 0.000199461454735274, 
        0.00685716972613716, 0.000594059423411153, -0.00396707849439904
        )), .Names = c("CHF.OPEN", "CHF.OPEN.1", "CHF50D", "CHF.OPEN.2"
    ), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", 
    "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", "2017-02-21", 
    "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
        AUD.CLOSE = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0), AUD.CLOSE.1 = c(1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), AUD.50D = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, 
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), AUD.CLOSE.2 = c(0.00640566933128534, 
        -0.00444038864633145, 0.00300594880983807, 0.0061146355869709, 
        -0.00207738324513479, -0.00390676366154397, 0.00312663099943206, 
        -0.00169237819473061, 0.00364156989756792, 0.00155662244429539
        )), .Names = c("AUD.CLOSE", "AUD.CLOSE.1", "AUD.50D", 
    "AUD.CLOSE.2"), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", 
    "2017-02-14", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", 
    "2017-02-21", "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(CAD.CLOSE = c(-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    -1), CAD.CLOSE.1 = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 
    -1), CAD.50D = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), CAD.CLOSE.2 = c(-0.00472778065310547, 
    -0.000917641725324381, 0.000382453058549392, 0.000305857167088586, 
    -0.000688310225637978, 0.00191080426541917, 0.000763300548471235, 
    0.00266697304419594, 0.00174871741959248, -0.00449199430572389
    )), .Names = c("CAD.CLOSE", "CAD.CLOSE.1", "CAD.50D", "CAD.CLOSE.2"
    ), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", 
    "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", "2017-02-21", 
    "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
        NZD.CLOSE = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1), NZD.CLOSE.1 = c(1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), NZD.50D = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, 
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), NZD.CLOSE.2 = c(0.00041733324664972, 
        -0.00208841008727045, -0.000836586774949688, 0.00750420419797471, 
        -0.00180142777185216, -0.00389105549296664, 0.00111327592906424, 
        -0.00404153570815258, 0.00390244397693174, 0.00568695616893883
        )), .Names = c("NZD.CLOSE", "NZD.CLOSE.1", "NZD.50D", 
    "NZD.CLOSE.2"), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", 
    "2017-02-14", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", 
    "2017-02-21", "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(SEK.OPEN = c(1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0
    ), SEK.OPEN.1 = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1), 
        SEK.50D = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), SEK.OPEN.2 = c(0.00163829609003363, 
        0.0023181988913219, -0.000716164076936199, -0.00145628918509555, 
        -0.00677152707834994, 0.00582941106111079, 0.00270059947077783, 
        0.00455540960162004, -0.000256248852460228, 0.00199255363165785
        )), .Names = c("SEK.OPEN", "SEK.OPEN.1", "SEK.50D", "SEK.OPEN.2"
    ), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", 
    "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", "2017-02-21", 
    "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
        NOK.CLOSE = c(1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), NOK.CLOSE.1 = c(-1, 
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), NOK.50D = c(1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), NOK.CLOSE.2 = c(0.00323283885094217, 
        0.00303175214315887, 0.000941075635438882, -0.00716968871997281, 
        -0.00617111408142934, 0.00665069589528811, -0.000467589464977269, 
        0.00246736261239189, 0.000837040274633605, -0.00324444329976892
        )), .Names = c("NOK.CLOSE", "NOK.CLOSE.1", "NOK.50D", 
    "NOK.CLOSE.2"), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", 
    "2017-02-14", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", 
    "2017-02-21", "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(CZK.CLOSE = c(1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    -1), CZK.CLOSE.1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), CZK.50D = c(1, 
    1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1), CZK.CLOSE.2 = c(0.00144601789180365, 
    0.00379617459269976, 0.00202579528819546, -0.00220231606416821, 
    -0.00688897736863447, 0.00560532297819627, 0.000184602212216056, 
    0.00710284457208665, -0.00197121312914339, -0.00224919172846905
    )), .Names = c("CZK.CLOSE", "CZK.CLOSE.1", "CZK.50D", "CZK.CLOSE.2"
    ), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", 
    "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", "2017-02-21", 
    "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
        HUF.LOW.1 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), HUF.LOW.1.1 = c(-1, 
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1), HUF.50D = c(1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), HUF.LOW.1.2 = c(0.0013470806658562, 
        0.00413351833762921, 0.000927691660614904, -0.00161542594720476, 
        -0.00908798735735505, 0.00843420139734707, -0.00110208028787984, 
        0.00632043873779775, -0.00133632598823841, 0.000719782039952932
        )), .Names = c("HUF.LOW.1", "HUF.LOW.1.1", "HUF.50D", 
    "HUF.LOW.1.2"), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", 
    "2017-02-14", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", 
    "2017-02-21", "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(ILS.LOW.1 = c(0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), ILS.LOW.1.1 = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
    ), ILS.50D = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), ILS.LOW.1.2 = c(0.000933818987030266, 
    0.000959590648321962, -0.00159982969276018, -0.00296644925366696, 
    -0.00509821862018822, -0.00393531505179312, 0.00242770943578163, 
    -0.00285991992901691, -0.000567559913074556, 0.00091874516690349
    )), .Names = c("ILS.LOW.1", "ILS.LOW.1.1", "ILS.50D", "ILS.LOW.1.2"
    ), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", 
    "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", "2017-02-21", 
    "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
        PLN.LOW.1 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), PLN.LOW.1.1 = c(-1, 
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), PLN.50D = c(1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), PLN.LOW.1.2 = c(-0.00274633685326608, 
        0.00755279414139087, 0.000417931735706034, -0.000491702529882065, 
        -0.00490565626173578, 0.00929781633628868, -0.00365469691428677, 
        0.00186580959045224, -0.00137446945036213, -0.00149934278232444
        )), .Names = c("PLN.LOW.1", "PLN.LOW.1.1", "PLN.50D", 
    "PLN.LOW.1.2"), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", 
    "2017-02-14", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", 
    "2017-02-21", "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(RUB.LOW.1 = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    -1, 1), RUB.LOW.1.1 = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 
    -1), RUB.50D = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), RUB.LOW.1.2 = c(-0.00446008580014645, 
    -0.0121748200414373, -0.00422818336649922, -0.0153488129381678, 
    0.0022241309795028, 0.00590173583792808, 0.014758577509606, 
    -0.00824954514944221, -0.00941636498473652, 0.0111898627811513
    )), .Names = c("RUB.LOW.1", "RUB.LOW.1.1", "RUB.50D", "RUB.LOW.1.2"
    ), row.names = c("2017-02-09", "2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", 
    "2017-02-14", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", 
    "2017-02-21", "2017-02-22"), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
        TRY.HIGH.1 = c(0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1), TRY.HIGH.1.1 = c(1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), TRY.50D = c(-1, -1, 
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), TRY.HIGH.1.2 = c(0.00417356089701015, 
        -0.00686579177053992, -0.00568012668941198, 0.00229778255761226, 
        0.00204713949728741, -0.0100024127023963, -0.00176420367173535, 
        -0.00113183078791668, -0.011249649909296, -0.00307744199905646
        )), .Names = c("TRY.HIGH.1", "TRY.HIGH.1.1", "TRY.50D", 
    "TRY.HIGH.1.2"), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", 
    "2017-02-14", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", 
    "2017-02-21", "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(ZAR.LOW.1 = c(-1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 
    -1), ZAR.LOW.1.1 = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 
    -1), ZAR.50D = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), ZAR.LOW.1.2 = c(-0.0050112296343281, 
    -0.000119978703923884, -0.0173679300039469, -0.0145343910929765, 
    0.00897924634581271, 0.000421926368602055, 0.000521408427958114, 
    0.00716476609655059, -0.0126608692527035, -0.00785440574245699
    )), .Names = c("ZAR.LOW.1", "ZAR.LOW.1.1", "ZAR.50D", "ZAR.LOW.1.2"
    ), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", 
    "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", "2017-02-21", 
    "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
        BRL.LOW.1 = c(0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1), BRL.LOW.1.1 = c(-1, 
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), BRL.50D = c(1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), BRL.LOW.1.2 = c(-0.00371652356533581, 
        -0.00160621962638552, -0.00832934597660584, -0.00902065874268554, 
        0.010543197464703, 0.00316721872930192, -0.00362049854021018, 
        0.00278119317749237, -0.0100617531753731, -0.0006199931673041
        )), .Names = c("BRL.LOW.1", "BRL.LOW.1.1", "BRL.50D", 
    "BRL.LOW.1.2"), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", 
    "2017-02-14", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", 
    "2017-02-21", "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(CLP.LOW.1 = c(-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), CLP.LOW.1.1 = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
    ), CLP.50D = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), CLP.LOW.1.2 = c(-0.00993671434599985, 
    0.00456853190734918, -0.00172828592427443, -0.00404432121904819, 
    -0.00048516719656444, 0.00933326604643625, -0.00561445365426927, 
    0.00353409520664982, -0.00208469536279665, -0.00105956972687871
    )), .Names = c("CLP.LOW.1", "CLP.LOW.1.1", "CLP.50D", "CLP.LOW.1.2"
    ), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", 
    "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", "2017-02-21", 
    "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
        COP.CLOSE = c(-1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, -1), COP.CLOSE.1 = c(-1, 
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), COP.50D = c(1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), COP.CLOSE.2 = c(-0.00197341552292052, 
        0.00662211307234362, 0.000580874632634121, -0.00202234392720335, 
        0.00204668459925017, 0.00543743450560008, -0.00266994190200176, 
        0.00607751193077277, -0.00217715796204931, -0.00905605289811184
        )), .Names = c("COP.CLOSE", "COP.CLOSE.1", "COP.50D", 
    "COP.CLOSE.2"), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", 
    "2017-02-14", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", 
    "2017-02-21", "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(MXN.LOW.1 = c(0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, -1, 
    -1), MXN.LOW.1.1 = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 
    -1), MXN.50D = c(-1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), MXN.LOW.1.2 = c(-0.000211320384603475, 
    -0.00314066280938086, -0.00107540683430729, 0.000705557901050646, 
    0.00518510570127306, 0.00240140867288519, -0.00281365838425973, 
    -0.0177295559643031, -0.00536567713104841, -0.0121193389083811
    )), .Names = c("MXN.LOW.1", "MXN.LOW.1.1", "MXN.50D", "MXN.LOW.1.2"
    ), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", 
    "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", "2017-02-21", 
    "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
        PEN.HIGH.1 = c(-1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, -1, 0), PEN.HIGH.1.1 = c(-1, 
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), PEN.50D = c(1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), PEN.HIGH.1.2 = c(-0.00429316820091041, 
        0.00214888801033619, -0.000859001157250239, -0.0038438522704316, 
        0.00101621330746293, 0.00460618041489735, -0.00522194398115183, 
        0, -0.000462071629322658, -0.000154071335332739)), .Names = c("PEN.HIGH.1", 
    "PEN.HIGH.1.1", "PEN.50D", "PEN.HIGH.1.2"), row.names = c("2017-02-10", 
    "2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", 
    "2017-02-20", "2017-02-21", "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(CNY.CLOSE = c(1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    -1), CNY.CLOSE.1 = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 
    -1), CNY.50D = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), CNY.CLOSE.2 = c(0.00135295379134326, 
    0.000247116371263401, -0.00184758230288495, 0.000524070878021865, 
    -0.0026376972616271, 0.001968002384513, 0.00174608993071379, 
    0.000799273430379666, -0.00090104498241117, -0.00170257391661588
    )), .Names = c("CNY.CLOSE", "CNY.CLOSE.1", "CNY.50D", "CNY.CLOSE.2"
    ), row.names = c("2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", 
    "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", "2017-02-21", 
    "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
        IDR.LOW.1 = c(-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), IDR.LOW.1.1 = c(-1, 
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1), IDR.50D = c(1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), IDR.LOW.1.2 = c(-0.00225360672301989, 
        0.00142787383820853, 0.000750694427567922, 0.000375135991193432, 
        -0.000825485019296579, 0.000975500021079156, 0.00157380030235466, 
        0.00142178345498323, -0.000448765901323256, -0.00119769458137853
        )), .Names = c("IDR.LOW.1", "IDR.LOW.1.1", "IDR.50D", 
    "IDR.LOW.1.2"), row.names = c("2017-02-09", "2017-02-10", 
    "2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", 
    "2017-02-21", "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(INR.LOW.1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
    ), INR.LOW.1.1 = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
    ), INR.50D = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1), INR.LOW.1.2 = c(-0.000466530150061928, 
    -0.000531550320954643, -0.000443420116883253, -0.000392023361358795, 
    -0.000386278564721287, -0.000386427833512393, -0.000244913256195467, 
    -0.000181510566847898, -0.000126929400856568, -0.000132850348706803
    )), .Names = c("INR.LOW.1", "INR.LOW.1.1", "INR.50D", "INR.LOW.1.2"
    ), row.names = c("2017-02-08", "2017-02-09", "2017-02-10", 
    "2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", 
    "2017-02-20", "2017-02-22"), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
        KRW.LOW.1 = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), 
        KRW.LOW.1.1 = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1
        ), KRW.50D = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), KRW.LOW.1.2 = c(0.000517860571988438, 
        0.000112542907102053, 0.00134952787013343, 0, -0.000337211266051574, 
        0.00112359562382647, 0.000449084996881899, 0.000785413785115541, 
        -0.00085276367906495, -0.000718681250895026)), .Names = c("KRW.LOW.1", 
    "KRW.LOW.1.1", "KRW.50D", "KRW.LOW.1.2"), row.names = c("2017-02-10", 
    "2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", 
    "2017-02-20", "2017-02-21", "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23"), class = "data.frame"))
```

Comment: your code errors in different place, this works `sum(FlaggingTrend[[x]][validrows, 4])`.

Comment: Yep this is the right answer... you beat me by 5 minutes.

Comment: @Bulat Oh wow.. I'm feeling silly. Thanks! This works but my output is now just a column of `NA`s? I tried looking over my code but I'm not seeing anything wrong with the way I wrote out my function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to address your problem, `d` being the content of your dput:

```
vapply(d, function(x) {
        valid_rows <- x[, 1] != 0 | x[, 2] > 0 |  x[, 3] != 0
        sum(x[valid_rows, 4])
 }, numeric(1))
```

A few things to note:

- first you say " first column is nonzero, second column is positive and third column is nonnegative" but you use `|` in your conditions. `|` means OR, if you want AND you would need to use `&`. In that case though, some of your examples don't match any rows, so you would get a sum of 0. If it's not what you want you'll need to modify the code to return NA when there is no rows that match your conditions, for instance:

  ```
  vapply(d, function(x) {
            valid_rows <- x[, 1] != 0 &  x[, 2] > 0 &   x[, 3] != 0
            if (sum(valid_rows)  > 0)
              sum(x[valid_rows, 4])
            else
              NA_real_
            }, numeric(1))
  ```
- second, for your last condition you say "third column is nonnegative", but you write `FlaggingTrend[[x]][,3] != 0` which tests for values different from 0, not positive values.
- third, it's best to not use global variables within your functions. It might lead to a lot of confusion down the road.
- here, I use `vapply` to enforce the data type of the returned objects. It's safer than `sapply` whose behavior can change depending on the data type of the returned objects.

Comment: Ahh I apologize. I meant to say or, not and. Given that, in the or case I should have valid rows and thus get back valid sums. However, with your `vapply` code I'm still getting just `NA` even after changing `&` to `|`. This might be a rather silly question, but is there anyway that the dput could be somehow be read differently than my global variable in R? I'm looking at my data right now and there are appropriate columns and data inputs.

And thanks for the tip about global variables! I'll try to wean myself off of that habit.

Comment: I am feeling really silly now because on closer inspection, I had `NA` floating in the first line of the data, which got omitted when I took the `dput(tail(x))`. I forgot R does that when you try to sum over `NA`s. Your code works perfectly fine. Thank you so much!!